# Creating Dr Racket scheme function that takes a list of evaluations in specific order and returns simplified version

Tags: scheme, racket

I am working towards being able to convert a list in the following way using Dr. Racket Scheme programming:

A function that takes in a list consisting of (9 7 / 8 7 /) would produce the list (7/9 7/8). The operator appears after the operands, with the right value (7 in both of these cases) being the first operand and the left-most value being the second operand. In order to achieve this, I have the following code:

```
(define (test original)
  (let loop ((original original)
        (new '()))
  (cond ((null? original) new)
        ((eq? (car original) '/)
         (cons (evaluate-expression (grab-last-two-values new) (car original))
               (loop (cdr original) (remove-last-two-values new))))
        (else
         (loop (cdr original) (cons (car original) new))))))

(define (grab-last-two-values ls)
  (cond ((null? (cdr (cdr ls))) ls)
        (else (grab-last-two-values (cdr ls)))))

(define (remove-last-two-values ls)
  (cond ((= (get-count ls) 2) '())
        (else (cons (car ls) (remove-last-two-values (cdr ls))))))

(define (evaluate-expression ls operator)
  (cond ((eq? operator '/) (/ (car ls) (car (cdr ls))))
        ((eq? operator '+) (+ (car ls) (car (cdr ls))))
        ((eq? operator '-) (- (car ls) (car (cdr ls))))
        ((eq? operator '*) (* (car ls) (car (cdr ls))))
        (else #f)))
```

In the case of the list being ( 9 7 / 8 7 / ), the test function works and returns the list (7/9 7/8). So all good there. However, when the list is ( 9 7 / 8 7 / / ), the function fails, when, ideally, it would return 1 and 1/8th, since 7/8 divided by 7/9 is 1 and 1/8th. I am not able to figure out how exactly to account for this. Any help/hints?

While evaluate expression will ultimately account for addition, subtraction, and multiplication in addition to division, I am only asking the question about division as that answer will apply to the rest.

Answer (score 0):

You are being asked to write a reverse Polish evaluator.  Do that rather than implementing a number of special cases.  Such a thing has a stream of forms which it is evaluating, a stack, and a table of operators.  Each operator knows how many arguments it expects which is a natural number, and has some implementation which is probably a function you can call on the arguments.

At each step it:

1. checks if the stream is empty: if it is return the current stack;
2. pick the first form of the stream

   1. if it names an operator, then pop as many arguments as the operator expects off the stack and invoke the operator's implementation on those arguments, pushing its result onto the stack;
   2. if it doesn't name an operator just push it onto the stack;
3. loop with the rest of the stream, the new stack and the table of operators.

You will also need a function which, given a stack, returns a stream of forms created by popping all the forms off the stack.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when you are working with lists, add or remove elements from beginning, not from end. Racket has already functions like `cddr` (removes first two values from list), `first` and `second`, so you can delete your `grab-last-two-values` and `remove-last-two-values`.

Start with the table of operators:

```
(define operators
  (list (cons '+ +)
        (cons '- -)
        (cons '* *)
        (cons '/ /)))
```

You will use [`assoc`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._assoc%29%29) function for searching in this list:

```
> (assoc '+ operators)
'(+ . #<procedure:+>)
```

Then write `evaluator` function, which takes list of forms as argument. This function calls some helper function (I used [`letrec`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/let.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fletstx-scheme..rkt%29._letrec%29%29) here, but it also can be global function), adding empty list as `stack` argument. Helper function checks every form in `args` and changes `stack` accordingly:

```
(define (evaluate args)
  (letrec ((evaluate-help
            (lambda (args stack)
              (cond ((empty? args) stack)
                    ((number? (car args))
                     (evaluate-help (cdr args) (cons (car args) stack)))
                    (else (evaluate-help (cdr args)
                                         (cons ((cdr (assoc (car args) operators)) (first stack) (second stack))
                                               (cddr stack))))))))
    (evaluate-help args '())))
```

If `args` is empty, `stack` is returned.

If `(car args)` is number, is pushed into `stack`.

Else new value, computed by `((cdr (assoc (car args) operators)) (first stack) (second stack))`, is pushed into `(cddr stack)`.

Examples:

```
> (evaluate '(9 7 / 8 7 /))
'(7/8 7/9)
> (evaluate '(9 7 / 8 7 / /))
'(1 1/8)
```

Answer (score 0):

A stack for operands and intermediate results is conventional, but given a *syntactically correct* reverse Polish expression (see other answers), the list can be evaluated "in  place":

```
(define (evaluate rpe)
  (cond
    [(not (memq '/ rpe)) rpe ]
    [(and (number? (car rpe))
          (number? (cadr rpe))
          (eq? (caddr rpe) '/))
      (let ([redex (cons (/ (cadr rpe) (car rpe)) (cdddr rpe))])
        (if (and (not (null? (cdr redex))) (number? (cadr redex)))
            (evaluate redex)
            redex)) ]
    [else (evaluate (cons (car rpe) (evaluate (cdr rpe)))) ]))

(check-expect (evaluate '(9 7 / 8 7 /))   '(7/9 7/8))
(check-expect (evaluate '(9 7 / 8 7 / /)) '(9/8))
(check-expect (evaluate '(2 2 9 7 / 8 7 / / / /)) '(9/32))
```

(works in Racket Intermediate Student Language and Scheme)